# Scala operator #> causes compilation error but not &> - why?

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, operators, type-inference, type-parameter

I have a type inference issue and asked for help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769848/scala-missing-parameter-type-in-type-class-operator/40770819). 
The initial problem was due to overload. Once corrected I
still had problems.

So here is the code:

```
class DPipe[ A ]( a: A ) {
  def !>[ B ]( f: A => B ) = Try(f( a ))
  def #>[ B, C ]( f: B => C )(implicit ev: A =:= Try[B]) : Try[C] = a.map(f)
  //def &>[ B, C ]( f: B => C )( implicit ev: A =:= Try[ B ] ) =  a.map( f )
}

object DPipe {
  def apply[ A ]( v: A ) = new DPipe( v )
}

object DPipeOps {
  implicit def toDPipe[ A ]( a: A ): DPipe[ A ] = DPipe( a )
}
```

And here are the tests:

```
object DPipeDebug {

 def main( args: Array[ String ] ) {

    import DPipeOps._

    val r8 = 100.0 !> {x : Double => x / 0.0}  
    println(r8)
    val r9 = r8 #> {x:Double => x* 3.0} 
    println(r9)
    /*
    val r8 = 100.0 !> { x: Double => x / 0.0 }
    println( r8.get )
    val r9 = r8 &> { x: Double => x * 3.0 }
    println( r9 )*/

    val r10 = (100.0 !> {x : Double => x / 0.0}) #> {x:Double => x* 3.0} 
   //val r10 = ( 100.0 !> { x: Double => x / 0.0 } ) &> { x: Double => x * 3.0 }

    val r11 = 100.0 !> {x : Double => x / 0.0} #> {x:Double => x* 3.0} 
    //val r11 = 100.0 !> { x: Double => x / 0.0 } &> { x: Double => x * 3.0     }
  }

}
```

As it stands we have the following error in the last code line:

```
Cannot prove that Double => Double =:= scala.util.Try[Double].
val r11 = 100.0 !> {x : Double => x / 0.0} #> {x:Double => x* 3.0} 
                                           ^
```

Notice that in the second last code line, I need only add
the parenthesis to enforce left left-hand associativity 
(Scala default). It seems like the `#>` operator tries to
use the function `{x : Double => x / 0.0}`, which indeed is a 
Double.

If however I use the "&>" operator, no error occurs. In the
test code below, just flip the comments. So my question is, why 
is this happening. Is this something new to Scala 2.12.0?

TIA

Comment: Not so new. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala

Comment: @Łukasz - I did not consider operator precedence. Blinded by the overload issue which led me to consider operator associativity. So this is the explanation I needed: # has higher precedence than ! (as per the link you made available). So can you make that an answer so that I can tag it as the correct one? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the operator precedence. Here are more details: [Operator precedence in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922347/operator-precedence-in-scala)

It depends on the first character of the operator. `#` has higher precedence than `!` and `!` has higher precedence than `&`.

Hence you get

```
100.0 !> ({x : Double => x / 0.0} #> {x:Double => x* 3.0})
```

instead of

```
(100.0 !> {x : Double => x / 0.0}) #> {x:Double => x* 3.0}
```